# List of banned market apps

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I recently came across fireplace market, which hosts fired apps banned by google. However it's apparently down.

I'm not really interested in the market app, I just would have liked to browse what Google does *not* like. Often such places offer nice to know niche apps.

Is there a list of banned-from-google-play apps?ds

EDIT: Does someone know what fireplace used to host?

Comment: IMO this has a number of issues -- too localized, asking for a list or just a link to an external resource, not really an "Android problem" but more of a "finding things problem", etc.  I don't think this is a good fit for the site.  Feel free to discuss on [Meta](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/) if you disagree.

Comment: I'm fine with that. you're right. close it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Such list could never be exhaustive as all the developers who got booted would need to collaborate to it.

Most warez markets don't exclusively deal with banned apps either, they usually host free and paid apps available in Play Store as well.

For the record the term "apps that Google doesn't like" is quite misleading. It's usually carriers or another external force that ask for removal of apps.

Comment: I don't mind if such a list is not exhaustive. There are plenty of apps that can only be downloaded at the authors website or anywhere else. It's more like looking for a source for interesting apps. Warez are defintely a big no-go. I'm not looking for malware. PS: Sorry for the 'misleading' part, wasn't meant that way. Firesheep's author was given a Nexus S for his university project by googlecode and some time later firesheep was just kicked off Google's market.

Comment: @ce4 In my country by my interpretation of the law firesheep is illegal. There's no such list apps that I'm aware of -  though a good source would be xda-developers "Android apps and games" section, if you can stand the people there :)